# Token Input Multiple Search Parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, input, jquery-tokeninput

I am using the TokenInput plugin but am having some issues when trying to have 2 input fields search by different parameters. They both search by the default in the jquery.tokeninput.js even though I have set the "propertyToSearch" option on both calls.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#your_dealership").tokenInput("_include/cpr_script.php", {
            theme: "facebook",
            tokenLimit: 1,
            preventDuplicates: true,
            propertyToSearch: "alias",
            hintText: "Find Your Dealership"
        });
        $("#rooftop_id").tokenInput("_include/cpr_script.php", {
            theme: "facebook",
            tokenLimit: 1,
            preventDuplicates: true,
            propertyToSearch: "id",
            hintText: "Find Your Dealership"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The JSON object returned looks like this:

```
{id:9880, alias:Longo Lexus, city:El Monte, state:California}
```

Currently, I have set "alias" as the propertyToSearch inside jquery.tokeninput.js, but I need to either have it search by id & alias or have a separate input field for each one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. My script's SQL query was being searched with the input value in the WHERE clause. I had to make another query if the search came from the id input.